# Scraping web sites with computer vision

Tags: python, selenium, machine-learning, web-scraping, computer-vision

I have been given the task to scrape a high number of websites. All of them represent (visually speaking) the data I'm interested in in a similar way. Each one of those websites has a product-details-view (so to call it). And all of the views contain the same information: a product title, price, maybe some images, a description, etc...

If I had to scrape 10 sites, I'd write 10 `if/else` or `case` in order to handle them, but I'm afraid the number of websites is quite bigger. And thus I'm getting into a whole other problem.

Then I figured out I'd use "computer vision" and "machine learning". That sounds reasonable in the sense of having almost identical websites and "teaching" an algorithm how to "see" the data I'm interested in.

My strategy, so far, is to render each product-detail-view in a headless chrome (controlled with selenium), take a screenshot and split the visual representation of the website into chunks: left column, main, right column. Then split the "main" part into several chunks: title, breadcrumb, content, etc...

Unfortunately I'm not really sure how to actually split the screenshot into chunks. I have been looking at OpenCV's docs, but I'm not sure it's suited for that concrete purpose (or is it?).

Are there any other libraries that would be a better fit for what I'm trying to do? Also, does my strategy sound good or are there better ways of approaching this problem?

PS: Diffbot, Import.io and similar are not an option. Please don't suggest them.

Comment: Please share some sample screenshots to illustrate the problem that you're facing

Comment: @SaranshKejriwal screenshot of what? Of the product detail view? Take as an example eBay or Amazon or any other e-commerce.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to solve the problem more engineering approach instead of machine learning. I mean to have one code for all the websites, but different *configs* for each of them. Some example of the config:

```
title: '#title_id',
description: '#description_id',
price: '#price_id'
```

Such approach will need some support in the future, because markup can be changed. But can be good to start for now.

Comment: I can't create 5000 configs. Literally it would take years.

Comment: 5000 - it's huge number. Not sure, that is possible for a one developer even with using computer vision...